# Запрос данных React + Apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть сервер qgraphql с которго я должен получить данные

Подключение:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Menu from '../Menu'
import DataType from '../DataType'
import Tabel from '../Table'
import tableData from '../../data'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'

const client = new ApolloClient({
uri:  'http://10.10.8.2/graphql/',
});

class App extends PureComponent
{
render(){
    return(
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <Menu/>
                <div className='col-9'>
                    <DataType/>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
                            <Tabel tableData={tableData}/>
                        </ApolloProvider>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default App
```

Запрос:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import TabelElement from './TableElement';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


class Table extends PureComponent{
render()
{
    const tableElement = this.props.tableData.map(tableData =>
        <TabelElement tableData={tableData}/>)

    const tableData = gql`
                           {
                            stations
                              {
                                id
                                name
                                createdAt
                                objectId
                                height
                                latitude
                                longitude
                                region{
                                  id
                                  name
                                  createdAt
                                  stations{
                                    createdAt
                                        name
                                  }
                                }
                              }

                            }
                        `;
    return(
        <table className='table'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Название</th>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">Широта</th>
                <th scope="col">Долгота</th>
                <th scope="col">Высота</th>
                <th scope="col">Статус</th>
                <th scope="col">Логи</th>
                <th scope="col">Пароль</th>
                <th scope="col">Последние получение данных</th>
                <th scope="col">Последние время наблюдения</th>
                <th scope="col">Последние ошибки</th>
                <th scope="col">Действия</th>
            </tr>
            <Query query={tableData}>
                {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                    if (loading) return "Loading...";
                    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

                    return (
                        <TabelElement tableData={data.stations.map(tableData => (
                            tableData
                        ))}/>
                    );
                }}
            </Query>
            </thead>
        </table>
    )
}
}

export default Table
```

TableElement:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

class TableElement extends PureComponent{
render(){
       const {tableData} = this.props
    return(
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.name}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.id}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.latitude}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.longitude}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.height}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.state}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.logi}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.password}</th>
            <th scope="col">{new Date(tableData.region.createdAt).toString()}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.last_observation}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.error}</th>
            <th scope="col">{tableData.doing}</th>
        </tr>
    )
}
}

export default TableElement
```

На выходе я получаю ошибку, может кто объяснить мне почему это происходит и где я не прав?

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку получаете? Тут вариантов может быть много... прикрепите содержимое ошибки и укажите место, где падает ошибка.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Error! Network error: Failed to fetch

Comment: Из замечаний, вы пытаетесь вывести данные внутри `thead` а нужно бы это делать внутри `tbody`. Константу запроса `gql` вынесите из метода рендера, лучше в отдельный файл. Внутри рендер метода компонента `Table` непонятная переменная `tableElement` которая не используется. Использование стрелочной функции в рендере создает новую функцию каждый раз, когда компонент отображается, что может иметь последствия для производительности - это  относится к `tableData={data.stations.map(tableData => (tableData))`, подготовьте данные заранее.

Comment: Инициализируйте апполо клиент так: `const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: createHttpLink({ uri: 'http://10.10.8.2/graphql' })
});` и добавьте импорты: `import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';` ну а перед этим не забудьте добавить npm-пакеты для этих импортов

Comment: @DenisBubnov я правильно понял что вы предлагаете перенести ApoloClient в <Table/>?

Comment: Нет, не правльно поняли. Вам нужно переписать свой имеющийся код на тот, который я написал в комментарии выше. Просто переписать, кстати, один импорт у вас уже есть для `createHttpLink`

Comment: @DenisBubnov я изменил client, перенос запрос в <tbody> и вынес строку запроса из класса, но теперь он выдаёт Error! Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: А это уже ошибка на стороне апполо сервера. Попробуйте выполнить простой запрос с выборкой не всех данных. Думаю, что вы допустили ошибку в описании запроса на стороне апполо. Для простой проверки можно это выполнять в браузере: [graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql)

Comment: Ну как? Удалось решить проблему с серверной стороной аполло?

Comment: @DenisBubnov Увы, но нет, я так и не понял как её исправить